# Find the critical points of the following system

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I want to find the critical points of the following three-dimensional system:

\begin{align}
\dot{x_1} &= x_1 - x_1x_2 - x_2^3 + x_3(x_1^2 + x_2^2 - 1 - x_1 + x_1x_2 + x_2^3)\\
\dot{x_2} &= x_1 - x_3(x_1 - x_2 + 2x_1x_2)\\
\dot{x_3} &= (x_3 - 1)(x_3 + 2x_3x_2^2 + x_3^3)
\end{align}
I know that the critical points of the system can be found by solving
\begin{align}
x_1 - x_1x_2 - x_2^3 + x_3(x_1^2 + x_2^2 - 1 - x_1 + x_1x_2 + x_2^3)= 0\\
x_1 - x_3(x_1 - x_2 + 2x_1x_2) = 0\\
(x_3 - 1)(x_3 + 2x_3x_2^2 + x_3^3) = 0
\end{align}
for $x$, so that's what I've tried to do. From the second equation I find that 
$$
x_3 = \dfrac{x_1}{x_1 - x_2+2x_1x_2}
$$
From the third equation I find that 
$$
x_2 = \sqrt{-1/2 - x_3^2/2}
$$
or $x_3 = 1$. Unfortunately, I don't really know how to proceed from here. If I plug in $x_3$ in $x_2$ I don't get anywhere. Furthermore, I don't know how to find $x_1$.

**Question:** How do I find the critical points of the system described above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with the 3rd equation
$$ (x_3-1)x_3(x_3^2+2x_2^2 + 1)=0.$$
Since the third factor is always positive, $x_3= 0$ or $x_3=1$.

**Case A: $x_3=0$.** Substituting $x_3=0$ in equation 2 gives $x_1=0$. Then equation 1 reduces to $-x_2^3 =0$, so $x_2=0$.

**Case B: $x_3=1$.** Substituting $x_3=1$ in equation 1 gives $x_1^2+x_2^2=1$. Moreover, equation 2 reduces to $x_2(1-2x_1)=0$. From the latter it follows that  $x_2=0$ or $x_1= 1/2$.

*Case B.1 $x_3=1$, $x_2=0$.* Equation 1 simplifies to $x_1^2=1$, so $x_1 = \pm 1$.

*Case B.2 $x_3=1$, $x_1=1/2$.* Equation 1 simplifies to $x_2^2=3/4$, so $x_2 = \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.